# Calculate from specific CSV columns and output to a new file

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to import data from one CSV file, make some calculations with the imported data, then save it to a new CSV file and I'm having no luck at all over the past day.

summary:

I have a pipe delimitated CSV with data columns:

colA, colB, colC, colD, colE

colA is a date time in a string format "20/01/2011 14:20:00"  (dd/MM/yyyy HHmmss)

colC is a number

I need to read the initial CSV, then from the value in colA, make two calculations:
1-the number of days since January 1st, 2000 and
2-the number of minutes from midnight.

EXAMPLE DATA in data.csv:

```
01/01/2011 14:20:00|10|6|10|192.168.11.7|
01/01/2011 14:25:00|2|0|10|192.168.11.7|
01/01/2011 14:30:00|4|8|10|192.168.11.7|
01/01/2011 14:35:00|6|9|10|192.168.11.7|
```

I then need to output the calculated data to a new CSV file, which also has some hard coded values / columns added to it (raw dta, no header):

(number of days since Jan 1 2000), (number of minutes from midnight), 5, (colC value), 1, Text, A, 0

** the values in brackets are calculated / or passed through from the original CSV. All other values are hard coded into each CSV ROW.

so for the EXAMPLE DATA above, the new output would be (again I've put in extra line breaks for formatting purposes):

```
4018,860,5,6,1,Text,A,0
4018,865,5,0,1,Text,A,0
4018,870,5,8,1,Text,A,0
4018,875,5,9,1,Text,A,0
```

I can get this far parsing the fields to an array like this:

```
$data = Import-Csv c:\data.csv -Header colA, colB, colC, colD, colE -Delimiter '|' | Select-Object colA, colC
$newdata += $data
$newdata | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ',' | foreach-object {$_} | Out-File c:\newfile.csv
```

this would give me the two fields I was after, but I was unable to perform the calculations and add the extra hard coded fields needed in the new CSV.

I've been googling and trying many, many different ways over the past day but I'm still getting nowhere.

Can anyone please offer some assistance?  Thank you.

Comment: Please add some sample data for input and desired output.

Comment: example data added to main body above.. please excuse the forced line breaks to preserve formatting.

Comment: I fixed it for you @gizmomelb. Now i can try my answer with your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should get you started

```
$path = "E:\temp\sample.csv"
$y2k = Get-Date -Date 1/1/2000
Import-Csv $path -Header colA, colB, colC, colD, colE -Delimiter '|' | ForEach-Object{
    $colADate = [datetime]::ParseExact($_.ColA,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
    $minutesFromMidnight = $colADate.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes
    $daysSincey2k = New-TimeSpan -Start $y2k -End $colADate | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Days
    [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
        DaysSince = $daysSincey2k
        MinutesSince = $minutesFromMidnight
        ColA = $_.Cola
        ColB = $_.Colb
        ColC = $_.Colc
        ColD = $_.Cold
        ColE = $_.Cole
    }
}
```

You could make this a one liner with `Select-Object` expressions but this should be alot easier to read. You should need at least PowerShell 3.0 for this to work. If you dont have it this would need only minor adjustments. This is the output with your data

```
DaysSince MinutesSince ColA                ColB ColC ColD ColE        
--------- ------------ ----                ---- ---- ---- ----        
     4018          860 01/01/2011 14:20:00 10   6    10   192.168.11.7
     4018          865 01/01/2011 14:25:00 2    0    10   192.168.11.7
     4018          870 01/01/2011 14:30:00 4    8    10   192.168.11.7
     4018          875 01/01/2011 14:35:00 6    9    10   192.168.11.7
```

If you times are all the same format using the method `ParseExact` will convert it to a `DateTime` object. That allows us to determine the difference of time using `New-TimeSpan`. Using the calculated fields make a custom object and add the calculated data.

**Update from Comments**

For the static output you are looking for I would change the `[pscustomobject]` as follows as well as adding an export-csv call

```
    [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
        DaysSince = $daysSincey2k
        MinutesSince = $minutesFromMidnight
        Five = 5
        ColC = $_.Colc
        One = 1
        Text = "Text"
        Bee = "B"
        Zero = 0
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path c:\newfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

For 2.0 this should work

```
    $props = @{
        DaysSince = $daysSincey2k
        MinutesSince = $minutesFromMidnight
        Five = 5
        ColC = $_.Colc
        One = 1
        Text = "Text"
        Bee = "B"
        Zero = 0
    }

    New-Object PSObject -Property $props
} | Select-Object DaysSince,MinutesSince,Five,ColC,One,Text,Bee,Zero | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\newfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for the suggestions / example @Matt

How do I export / save the Colc, DaysSince and MinutesSince to a new file please?

so the export format is:

DaysSince,MinutesSince,5,ColC,1,Text,B,0

Thank you.

Comment: @gizmomelb updated with your data as input. Have a look

Comment: Thanks @Matt - some of that even makes sense to me, so thank you very much for your help.     But I want to save the DaysSince, MinutesSince and colC values to a new CSV file, which also has some hard coded fields added to each row - how would I approach that please? Thank you.

Comment: @gizmomelb have a look at the __bold__ section for your request.

Comment: thank you and thank you for being an excellent teacher - I was just searching and was going to ask if I needed to use the Export-CSV command.  I didn't realise you could hard code values in the array as it was saved to CSV format.  Thank you again so much for your assistance and time.

Comment: sigh.. it's never easy.  Unfortunately we're locked to Powershell v2.0  for the machine this will be running on - what changes do I have to make please, as this is aimed at Powershell v3.0?  Thank you.

Comment: @gizmomelb check my answer again for an update near the bottom

Comment: you are a legend!  Thank you.  I was checking the differences in command structure between PS3.0 and 2.0 to try to figure out myself, but quite a lot of reading.  Thank you once again for your invaluable assistance and patience.

Comment: just as a final wrap up to this - I changed the last bit of the script 'export-csv $FullFileName -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ',' ' so that I could choose if I wanted headers or not, as well as strip out the quoatation marks surrounding each piece of data - 'convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ',' | select -skip $(if($IncludeHeadersInExport -eq $TRUE){0}else{1}) | % { $_ -replace '"', ""} | % { $_ -replace '"', ""} | foreach-object {$_} | Out-File $FullFileName'

Comment: where $IncludeHeadersInExport is a true or false variable configured earlier in the script and $FullFileName is defined as a set directory with the filename having the date and timestamp appended to it.  I hope this is of help to someone else!